# Google Cloud Spanner Merge SQL Equivalent process in Python using Google API's

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, sql-merge

How to perform a Merge SQL as stated below in Google Cloud Spanner using Google API's?

```
MERGE INTO TABLE2 B 
USING (SELECT COL1, COL2, SUM(TOTAL_CNT) 
 FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY COL1, COL2) A 
   ON (B.COL1=A.COL1 AND B.COL2 = A.COL2)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET B.TOTAL_CNT = B.TOTAL_CNT + A.TOTAL_CNT) 
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (COL1, COL2, TOTAL_CNT) 
VALUES (A.COL1.A.COL2,A.TOTAL_CNT)
```

Comment: Can you rephrase this into a real question? So that your Question/Answer is more like the ones mentioned in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: @Scratte, rephrased the question. Let me know if this needs to be refined more.

Comment: The more detail you can provide, the better. You could add an example where you'd like to merge and show the results you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have to perform merge SQL, it needs to be broken down to 2 steps.
First step is to do a left join with Target Table and get the values you want and  with the result set, we have to perform Batch Insert_or_update. This will save lot of look-ups and is more efficient. I've made the Batch Insert_or_update as multithreaded so that you can trigger more threads and process will finish quicker. If you don't need to be that fancy then you can make it as in-line code.

```
    '''
    import threading
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    import time
    from merge_ins_upd_using_df import merge_ins_upd_using_df 
    from google.cloud import spanner

    # Instantiate a client.
    spanner_client = spanner.Client()

    # Your Cloud Spanner instance ID.
    instance_id = 'spanner-instance'

    # Get a Cloud Spanner instance by ID.
    instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id)

    # Your Cloud Spanner database ID.
    database_id = 'database-id'

    max_thread_cnt = 30
    threadLimiter = threading.BoundedSemaphore(max_thread_cnt)
    thread_list = []
    thread_count = 0
    thread_cnt_before = 0
    thread_counter = 0

         
    sql_stmt = """ (SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, SUM(A.TOTAL_CNT +  COALESCE(B.TOTAL_CNT,0)) AS TOTAL_CNT
                      FROM (SELECT COL1, COL2, SUM(TOTAL_CNT) AS TOTAL_CNT 
                      FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY COL1, COL2) A 
                      LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B on (A.COL1 = B.COL1 AND A.COL2 = B.COL2) """
                    

    spanner_client = spanner.Client()
    instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id )
    database = instance.database(database_id)
    with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
         results = snapshot.execute_sql(sql_stmt)

    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df.columns = ['COL1', 'COL2', 'TOTAL_CNT']

    process_cnt = 10  # set this count based on the number of columns/index updates so that it wont go beyond 20,000 mutations limit
    rec_cnt = df.shape[0]
    print('Total Rec Count: ' + str(rec_cnt))
    total_rec_processed = 0 
    from_index = 0 
    to_index = 0
    dest_table = 'TABLE2'

    ### Build the threads

    while True:
        from_index = to_index
        to_index = to_index + process_cnt
        thread_counter = thread_counter + 1
        if to_index > rec_cnt:
           to_index = rec_cnt
        df1 = df[from_index:to_index]
        thread_count += 1
        t = threading.Thread(target=merge_ins_upd_using_df,args=(instance_id, database_id, df1, thread_counter, dest_table))
        thread_list.append(t)
        total_rec_processed = total_rec_processed + process_cnt
    #    print("Threads Added: " + str(thread_count) + "Proc Count:" + str(total_rec_processed ))
        if total_rec_processed >= rec_cnt:
           break 

    begin = datetime.datetime.now()

    print("Thread Kick-off has Started : " + str(begin))

    print ("Thread Count before :" +  str(threading.active_count()))

    thread_cnt_before = threading.active_count()

    # Starts threads
    for thread in thread_list:
        while threading.active_count() >= max_thread_cnt:
              time.sleep(.05)
        thread.start()
        
    print ("Thread Count after :" +  str(threading.active_count()))

    print("All Threads have been kicked off : " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))    

    if thread_count > 0:
       while threading.active_count() > thread_cnt_before:
             time.sleep(2)

    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    diff = end-begin
    print("Total time for completion in minutes : " + str(diff.total_seconds()/60))


   #######  function - merge_ins_upd_using_df
 class merge_ins_upd_using_df:
  def __init__(self, cs_instance, cs_database, df, thread_counter, dest_table):
    self.cs_instance = cs_instance
    self.cs_database = cs_database
    self.thread_counter = thread_counter
    self.df = df
    self.dest_table = dest_table

    from google.cloud import spanner
    import datetime

    begin = datetime.datetime.now()
               
    spanner_client = spanner.Client()
    instance = spanner_client.instance(cs_instance)
    database = instance.database(cs_database)

    with database.batch() as batch:
         batch.insert_or_update(
          table=dest_table, columns=df.columns,
          values=df.values.tolist())
    
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    diff = end-begin
### add logic to handle exceptions
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can use similar SQL clauses such as union and intersect to achieve your goal, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265851/does-google-cloud-spanner-support-index-intersection-combination-merge) elaborates on the goal. I think your approximation in your response using joins is also good.